# Trying to write a simple program that calculates GC content in a DNA strand. Why does this keep giving a {Null^2} output?

Tags: functions, output

```
GCcontent[n_] := Module[{calcs, total, GCpercent},
  calcs = 
   Map[Length[StringCases[StringReplace[n, " " -> ""], #]] &, {"A", 
     "T", "G", "C"}];
  GCpercent = (calcs[[3]] + calcs[[4]])/Total[calcs];
  Apply[Print[#1, " = ", #2] &, {{"A", 474}, {"T", 600}, {"G", 
      387}, {"C", 371} }, {1}]
   Print["Sequence length: ", Total[calcs], "\n", "GC content: ", 
    N@GCpercent]
  ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You need a semicolon between the last two statements (`Apply` and `Print`) in your module. Would be interested to have you supply us with one example data. If it is too large, maybe a simpler sample.

Answer (score 2):

The expression you're returning is:

```
Apply[Print[#1, " = ", #2] &, {{"A", 474}, {"T", 600}, {"G", 387}, {"C", 371}}, {1}] * Print["Sequence length: ", Total[calcs], "\n", "GC content: ", N@GCpercent]
```

Let's look at the form of that thing:

```
Times[Apply[Print[#]&, list, {1}], Print[thing]]
```

`Print` always returns `Null`. Therefore `Apply[Print, list, {1}]` always returns `{Null, Null, …}` for as many elements as `list` has. We then pointwise-multiply by `Print["Sequence length: ", …]` which also evaluates to `Null`. This results in the same thing as

```
ConstantArray[Null^2, Length@list]
```

but with some side-effects caused by `Print` - namely, the printing of some things.

Comment: Although you get my +1 for a useful analysis I think the shorter answer is: Orion is missing a `;` between the two `Print` expressions.